# visual studio 2015 multi-monitor tool window dragging

Tags: windows, visual-studio

The behavior I'm about to describe extends across computers and versions of Visual Studio (2013/2015) and Windows (7, 10).

I like to have my solution explorer and diagnostic tools as floating windows, and put them on other monitors so that my code monitor is just code.  But, in doing this, I've invariably encounter the odd behavior that when dragging a floating window, such as the solution explorer, across a monitor divide, that the mouse and the window title bar and window outline become out of sync.  My mouse is ahead of the window now.  Then, my mouse reaches the edge of the monitor and can go no further but the tool window is still way behind.

I actually have four monitors, and so often the window will be two monitors back.

Furthermore, these undocked windows ignore Window's sticky-edge policy.  Although I have sticky edges turned off, and other programs behave when dragging across monitor divides, these windows stick to every edge.

The long and the short of it is that these windows hardly work at all in a multi-monitor situation and manipulating them makes VS feel like a half-baked torture device.

Is there something I can do to fix this myself?  Does anyone else see this behavior?

Comment: The drawbacks of a development group that wasted time rolling their own inferior "windows" instead of using the functionality provided by the operating system. Don't they *look cool*, though?